# Why Dialog doesn't dismiss immediately in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dialog, alert, navigator

Dialog doesn't dismiss immediately on Yes button pressed with Navigator.of(context).pop(true), it waits to complete for loop execution, after posting the complete data dialog dismiss, I need it to dismiss immediately when button is pressed the want then want to show circular bar, how to resolve this, please help, thanks in advance

```
Widget getPostButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 10.0, 15.0, 15.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        shape: StadiumBorder(),
        child: Text("Post New Request"),
        onPressed: () {
          if (_requestFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Are you sure?'),
                    content: Text("Are you sure to post new request?"),
                    backgroundColor: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .primaryColor,
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                          shape: StadiumBorder(),
                          child: Text("Yes, Post request"),
                          onPressed: () =>
                          {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop(true)
                          }),
                      RaisedButton(
                        shape: StadiumBorder(),
                        color: Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .errorColor,
                        child:
                        Text("No", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                }).
            then((value) {
              print('Result: ' + value.toString());
              if (value) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    RequestsService.addRequest(request).then((value) => {});
                  }
               }
            });
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of chaining like `return AlertDialog(...).then(...)`, you can do something as follows:

```
bool process = await AlterDialog(..);
if (process) {
   // Show Circular progress indicator
   // perform calculation
   // pop out circular progress indicator
}
```